# How to list non published articles in T-SQL

Tags: sql, replication

How can i list all **TABLES** and **STORE PROCEDURES** which are **not** published in publication DB with T-SQL query?

Tables in RED are example ...

[This is an example which tables and store procedures have to be listed](http://i39.tinypic.com/2py2pt2.png)

Comment: Is this missing a screenshot or something?

Comment: i 've added it right now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not have a replication set up, so I cannot actually build or check a query, but I'm fairly certain that the information you are looking for can be found in the [`syspublications`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188027.aspx) and [`sysarticles`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187723.aspx) tables.

As an additional help, try checking one of the boxes. In the upper-left section of the screenshot, there's a button called `Script` that's currently disabled. Making a change (like checking or unchecking a check-box) should give you the ability to see what the check-box setting actually changed in which tables.

Lastly, you could start Profiler, and then open the screen. If you'd check the check-box marked `Show only checked articles in the list`, that would limit the selection of the main window to only the checked articles. Profiler would then be able to let you see what script was executed to obtain those results.

Comment: Hi Schmitz! Thanks for helping me out ... but SCRIPT button is grayed out and cannot do nothing with it ... i tried with Profiler also .. but with no luck ... to many things is going on on DB and cannot quick find what is the right command when i click on "Show only checked articles in the list"

Comment: Beside that ... i would also like to list those tables and store procedures from the picture i have added which are in round brackets also!

so it would list for example:

ApprovalConfiguration(**ApprovalManagement**)
...
...
and so on ...

Comment: @Seronjsky Try limiting the events captured in Profiler to those from your system only? Alternatively, save the output to a table so you can query it there. As for the text in the brackets, that looks like the schema the tables are in. You can grab that by joining with sybsojects.

Comment: I manage to do: `SELECT
    * 
FROM sysobjects WITH (NOLOCK) 
WHERE ((xtype = 'U') OR (xtype = 'P')) AND 
    category <> 2 AND 
    name NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT object_name(OBJID) FROM sysarticles)
    ORDER BY xtype asc` but there is no schema that the tables are in :(

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I missed a dot in there. Try using `sys.objects`, which then can be joined to `sys.schemas`. I.e. `SELECT s.name, o.name FROM sys.objects o JOIN sys.schemas s ON o.schema_id = s.schema_id`

Comment: I got it! Here it is:

Comment: `SELECT s.name AS SCHEMA_NAME, o.name AS OBJECT_NAME, o.type_desc FROM sys.objects o JOIN sys.schemas s ON o.schema_id = s.schema_id
WHERE o.is_published='0'
and o.is_schema_published='0'
and (o.type='P' or o.type='U')
and s.name not in ('dbo')
and o.name not like 'SqlQueryNotificationStoredProcedure%'
and o.name not like 'QRTZ_BLOB_TRIGGER%'
and o.name not in ('Job_Checkpoints_Log','LPChatImportLog','LPChatImportError','Queue')
ORDER BY o.type_desc asc`

Comment: This will show only tables and store procedures which are not published!

Comment: Nice :) Glad I could assist you to some extent.

Answer (score 0):

This will get a list of all tables, views, and stored procedures that are not published in a publication database.

For Snapshot and Transactional:

```
SELECT
    name 
FROM sys.objects WITH (NOLOCK) 
WHERE (([type] = 'U') OR ([type] = 'V') OR ([type] = 'P')) AND 
    is_ms_shipped <> 1 AND
    name NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT object_name(OBJID) FROM sysarticles)
```

For Merge:

```
SELECT
    name 
FROM sys.objects WITH (NOLOCK) 
WHERE ((type = 'U') OR (type = 'V') OR (type = 'P')) AND 
    is_ms_shipped <> 1 AND 
    name NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT object_name(OBJID) FROM sysmergearticles)
```

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT object_name(OBJID) FROM sysmergearticles returns only tables. What about comparing against views and procedures?